# Pass large array of objects to RabbitMQ exchange

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I receive large array of objects from an external source (about more than 10 000 objects). And then I pass it to exchange in order to notify other microservices about new entries to handle.

```
this._rmqClient.publishToExchange({
    exchange: 'my-exchange',
    exchangeOptions: {
        type: 'fanout',
        durable: true,
    },
    data: myData, // [object1, object2, object3, ...]
    pattern: 'myPattern',
})
```

The problem is that it's bad practice to push such large message to exchange, and I'd like to resolve this issue. I've read articles and `stackoverflow` posts about that to find code example or information about streaming data but with no success.

The only way I've found out is to divide my large array into chunks and publish each one to exchange using `for ... loop`. Is it good practice? How to determine what length should each chunk (number of objects) have? Or maybe is there another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the `Object` size.. That's a thing you would have to figure out yourself. Get your 10k objects and calculate an average size out of them (Put them as json into a file and take `fileSize/10'000` that's it. Maybe request body size of 50-100kb is a good thing? But that's still up to u ..

Start with number *50* and do tests. Check the time taken, bandwidth and everything what makes sense. Change chunk sizes from between 1-5000 and test test test .  At some point, you will get a feeling what number would be good to take! .

Here's some example code of looping through the elements:

```
// send function for show caseing the idea.
function send(data) {
    return this._rmqClient.publishToExchange({
        exchange: 'my-exchange',
        exchangeOptions: {
            type: 'fanout',
            durable: true,
        },
        data: data,
        pattern: 'myPattern',
    })
}

// this sends chunks one by one.. 
async function sendLargeDataPacket(data, chunkSize) {

    // Pure functions do prevent headache
    const mutated = [...data]

    // send full packages aslong as possible!.
    while (mutated.length >= chunkSize) {

        // send a packet of chunkSize length
        await send(mutated.splice(0, chunkSize))

    }

    // send the remaining elements if there are any!
    if(mutated.length > 0) {
        await send(mutated)
    }

}
```

And you would call it like:

```
// that's your 10k+ items array!.
var myData = [/**...**/]

// let's start with 50, but try out all numbers!.
const chunkSize = 50
sendLargeDataPacket(chunkSize).then(() => console.log('done')).catch(console.error)
```

This approach send one packet after the other, and may take some time since it is not done in parallel. I do not know your requirements but I can help you writing a parallel approach if you need..

Comment: Hmmm.. okay, i'he counted the average size of each object (it's up to ~430 B). So I receive an array of size ~4.36 MB. I'm not sure about recommended message body size of AMPQ (it's up to ~131 KB -- please, correct me if I'm mistaken), but let's suggest then we want to have each chunk `(131 * 1000) / 436 = 300` elements long. So we need to publish 33 messages to the queue. Okay, let's imagine I restricted number of entries (~5000 -- so that it's ~15 messages). What should I do? Keep all these messages being waiting for each of them will be processed?

Comment: Does the order matter for sending? If not, then send them in parallel with a `request per second` limit.

Comment: No, not in parallel. I need to send messages sequentially (i thought rabbitmq can't keep so many messages in one queue). But now everything's okay. So, thx for code